# How to make checkboxes check on double-click only?

Tags: excel, vba

I have check boxes in an excel spreadsheet in cells that also contain values (dates). To avoid  administrators accidentally checking boxes when they are clicking on the cell, I want to adapt the check box so that one has to double-click to register a tick. I don't want to protect the worksheet because there is more than one person editing information on an ongoing basis. Any ideas?

[image: column with checkbox][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbLsU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this system. Install in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have the checkboxes.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim ChkVal() As Boolean
    Dim EnableChk As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 27 Oct 2017

    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim Sn As String

    ReDim ChkVal(Me.Shapes.Count)
    For Each Shp In Me.Shapes
        With Shp
            If .Type = 12 And InStr(1, .Name, "checkbox", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                ChkVal(Val(Mid(.Name, 9))) = .OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
            End If
        End With
    Next Shp
End Sub

Private Sub CbxChange(Cbx As MSForms.CheckBox)
    ' 27 Oct 2017

    Dim Id As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    With Cbx
        Id = Val(Mid(.Name, 9))
        If Not EnableChk Then
            Do Until .Value = ChkVal(Id)
                .Value = Not .Value
            Loop
        Else
            ChkVal(Id) = .Value
        End If
    End With
    EnableChk = False

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err = 9 Then
        Worksheet_Activate
        Resume 0
    Else
        MsgBox "A programming error interrupted this procedure.", _
                vbInformation, "Unidentified error"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    CbxChange CheckBox1
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    EnableChk = True
End Sub
```

You will need a pair of event procedures like the last two for every checkbox on your sheet. I tried a quick way to do that.

1. Select the two procedures.
2. Press Ctl+C to copy
3. Press Ctl+V twice (the first over-writes the existing selection, the second creates a copy)
4. Select the copied pair
5. Edit -> Replace "1" with "2" -> OK
   VBA will check "Selected text" automatically. Don't change that. Make sure that "Find whole word only" is *not* checked. 3 replacements will be made, and that is all there is to it.